# Installing AngularJS Package in Sublime Text 3

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext3

I installed Package Control in Sublime Text 3 and was able to install Emmet through the following

https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

Now when I go to Preferences->Package Control and try to install AngularJS it does not show up as an option. Nor do many other packages show up as an option. How can I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to solve this

Comment: Can you kindly answer your own question and accept the answer so that this question does not come in unanswered questions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved in the following way to install new packages.

In sublime-text typing Ctrl+Shift+P.. 'type in installed packages' and click on the Installed Packages text that is prompted.

In that text box look for the package and click on it. Sublime Text will install the package.